# How to create a personalized windows iso install disk?

Tags: untagged

I've got the Win7 iso from Microsoft website. Microsoft released a language pack for pt-br, and now I want create a new disk from the win7 ISO file and just add the language pack file in the same disk.

But ISO recorder tools like ImgBurn doesn't shows options to edit the ISO file (to add the file) before record the disk image.

There is some free tool to get that job done?

Answer (score 3):

The Windows AIK is the officially supported way of doing this, and is available for the Windows 7 RC (discussion here: http://www.mydigitallife.info/2009/05/06/windows-automated-installation-kit-aik-for-windows-7-rc-official-download/ )

You should note though that it requires quite a bit more work that you may be happy with, but you can be certain that the end result will be a viable ISO image.

Comment: windows AIK will help you edit the unattended file of windows installer

Answer (score 2):

[vLite](http://www.vlite.net/) might be what you're looking for. Works with Vista, but still untested with Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

Use mdt to build a custom windows install.  You can do similar things with the waik alone but while you are customizing you might as well toss in your favorite apps. It's also easier than using just the waik.